# Just curious what goes into the decision between using UDP and TCP when creating an online game

Tags: tcp, udp

As the title suggests, I was wondering how one decides which protocol to implement.  So far I understand that UDP can make for faster transmission of data but with the order it's sent in neglected and it doesn't monitor if the data is even received.  To my knowledge TCP is safer and is used when data has to be precise and the reception time doesn't have to be as swift.  But I noticed that different online games use different protocols even though all of them games play quite fluently(which I'm assuming means fast data transfer.)  So I'm wondering how can you tell which is used, and why is that protocol used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: incoming oversimplification.  Still, this should help you understand.

TCP is reliable.  If you send data, it will either get there in one piece and in perfect order, or it won't get there.  This reliability comes at a cost of more traffic overhead, because the receiver has to acknowledge its receipt to the sender, and the sender may send the same data multiple times to ensure correct delivery.

UDP is unreliable, but with no such overhead.  The sender tosses packets at the receiver.  Packets that do arrive are still guaranteed to arrive in one piece, but not all packets are guaranteed to arrive.  UDP is useful when you can afford transmission loss and the overhead of TCP is too great to justify the reliability.

Examples of uses for UDP include real-time content streaming (video/audio) and continuous state updates (*e.g.*, packets notifying the client of the state of various objects in your game universe).  In general, these are adequate targets because data becomes irrelevant very quickly as it is replaced with new data.  Better to keep throwing bits and chugging along than to worry about intact arrival of past data that may no longer matter.

On the other hand, something like authentication, a content updating system, or in-game chat would strongly benefit from a more reliable TCP connection, as latency is far less important than integrity.

Comment: edit your reply if you have further data, comments are for, well, comments.

Comment: I see, thanks for the response!  But if that was the simplified version, what subtleties were left out? Or what is an example of one?

Comment: I think it really does cover the bulk of the rationale one would use to select a socket type for any given purpose.  The warning is more of a disclaimer to protect against unforeseen subtleties in various edge cases (*i.e.*, maybe your specific application has some odd requirement whereby your volumes of real-time data must be reliably communicated).

Comment: And to your example, how would one be able to compensate for both of the protocols flaws, or lacking areas, in order to achieve speed and reliability? (Last question, I promise :P)

Comment: By design, you simply choose the protocol that fits the task.  Use UDP when the effects of unreliable data are easily swept under the rug by the constant replacement of that data.  If you miss a frame that says object #42 is now at position <4,5,6>, it doesn't really matter because a moment later you'll very likely receive the frame that says object #42 is now at position <5,6,7>.  You don't do anything to compensate for the flaws, you simply use each protocol in places where their respective flaws are largely inconsequential.

Answer (score 0):

The reliable way to tell which protocol is used is to use a network packet sniffer that records your network traffic, record some of the game related traffic and look at the protocol name. One example of a free and simple network sniffer is Wireshark (formerly Ethereal).

The UDP vs TCP decision will probably (I say probably as I am not a professional game dev, just a hobby dev) boil down to the amount of traffic you expect to send/receive, the networking conditions, the durability of the program in case of packet loss and the expected number of concurrent users.

A turn based strategy game, for example chess, in which each player need not send much more than their moves and occasional chat messages, would benefit from TCP. A first-person shooter with dozens of players in a 3D might generate a lot of traffic over a long time but might not suffer if a few packets now and then are lost, making it an ideal candidate for UDP.

Then again, some games might even use a combination of TCP and UDP for tasks with different requirements in speed and reliability.

Comment: I was reading an article on a few MMOs though and they were said to be mainly TCP based.  How could that be when all that data has to be transmitted in real time? Or did I just misinterpret the article?

Comment: I've read that some companies use algorithms to extrapolate user input from earlier input, as in if the player was walking forward last packet, they will probably be walking forward in the same direction in the next packet, and the server will have them walk forward even if that next packet is lost. Perhaps they were using a combination of one of these algorithms and slow TCP?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it as "UDP is faster" and "TCP is slower", because that's just wrong. The big difference is that bad packets are just dropped in UDP. The receiver UDP implementation **won't have to wait for the dropped packet to be retransmitted and received before delivering any subsequent ones to the application**.

In TCP, even if your machine has the next packet after the dropped one in a buffer, it won't be able to deliver it to the application until the sender retransmits the one that was dropped.

TCP: deliver data to app in order, automatic retransmit
UDP: deliver data to app in any order, no retransmit

UDP mostly makes sense if the packets are self contained. If you have to reassembly multiple UDP packets into one, you should probably use TCP.